# R: creating a new variable by merging the contents of two variables in

Tags: r, variables, na

I have a dataframe a with two variables that represents two types of people. The way the df is set now is that for one variable there are NAs when the values don't represent person A and in the second variable there are NAs where the values don't represent person b. I want to combine these two variables so that I just have 1 variable.

The DF looks something like this:

```
Total <- rep(c(1, NA, NA, 5) , 1)
Total2 <-rep( c(NA, 8,9,NA), 1)
data <- data.frame(Total, Total2)
```

I would like to add a third variable that looks like this:

```
  Total <- rep(c(1, NA, NA, 5) , 1)
    Total2 <-rep( c(NA, 8,9,NA), 1)
   All_var = rep(c(1,8,9,5), 1)
   data <- data.frame(Total, Total2, All_var)
```

I've tried this, but I just get a new variable with the same values as Total.

```
data$All_var=data$Total
data$All_var[is.na(data$Total)]=data$Total2[is.na(data$Total)]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R try:

```
data$newvar <- replace(data$Total, is.na(data$Total), data$Total2[is.na(data$Total)])
```

Or using `coalesce` with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(newvar = coalesce(Total, Total2))
```

Comment: Oddly, that works with the data reproducible dataframe I included, but not on my actual dataframe. The mutate function in dplyr actually gives me two new variables that mimic the two variables I'm trying to combine and the replace function just gives me the value for the one variable. It's strange. It should be more or less the same.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I appreciate your help.